# 2 problems. One, my left leg armature moves my entire body, and when i tried to fix it i couldn't see my vertices

Tags: armature, bones, vertices

I'm quite a beginner in blender, I don't really know alot about bones and armature, so I made it with the skin modifier witch I have since applied. Basically I need to know how i can see my vertices and then fix the bones.

No vertices:
[image: no vertices]

Leg bone:
[image: leg bone]

Comment: Are the vertices in question the vertices on your model? If so, go into object mode, select your character then go back to edit mode. It looks like currently you are in the edit mode of your armature.

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: I tried to do that but, after a while my blender gets so laggy i can't tell if i've selected something. I guess i didn't notice, thanks.

Comment: @Chris [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Yz9NlOEy" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Yz9NlOEy/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you change viewport display to octahedral ...

[image]

you can see the reason:

[image]

your leg bones have the wrong direction, so select these bones in edit mode and choose armature -> switch direction

[image]

after that you have to correct the parenting like this:

select the child bone, then the parent bone, then press CTRL-P -> connected

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I've looked in so many places and couldn't find the answer.

Comment: You are welcome